# Error output while installing node

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc1rp.png)
hello there,
Am trying to install Phonegap, in the process i have to install node, the picture is the error output while installing node

Comment: When you want to convey information present in your terminal, please copy the text and paste it here using [this site's formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **NVM** (Node Version Manager) to manage and install Node.js. It seems like an extra step, but you will be worries free regarding to **node** configuration.

To install NVM (From the [GitHub Docs](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), where you  have other installation alternatives):

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

After this, you could just do:

For latest **node** release:

```
nvm install node
```

For **Long Term Support (LTS)**:

```
nvm install --lts
```